# is there anyway i can implement tradingview widget (chart) in react-native mobile app?

Tags: react-native, tradingview-api

i am building a mobile app and i need to show the user the trading view chart so that they can use.
i have searched and i haven't seen any react-native package for implementing the chart.

i am building a mobile app and i need to show the user the trading view chart so that they can use.
i have searched and i haven't seen any react-native package for implementing the chart.

i am building a mobile app and i need to show the user the trading view chart so that they can use.
i have searched and i haven't seen any react-native package for implementing the chart.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to do this right now. As a turnaround, I used [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) library for this purpose. My code implementation is as follows:

```
<WebView
          forceDarkOn
          style={{
            backgroundColor: THEME.COLORS.primaryBackground,
          }}
          source={{
            uri: `https://www.tradingview.com/chart?symbol=usd`,
          }}
          useWebKit={true}
          originWhitelist={['https://www.tradingview.com']}
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
          incognito
        />
```

Please note that I have used incognito and originWhitelist params. Incognito for disabling cache as trading view will display a non dismiss ad after some time and originWhitelist for disabling popup ads that open new windows.

Comment: Just what I need but the Incognito and originWhitelist are not working anymore.